# Entity Framework IQueryable with join

Tags: join, frameworks, entity

I'm new with Entity Framework and razor pages, I´m very familiar with asp classic, but know I'm trying to learn something more actual.
How can I retrieve values from a join query in a model to the page/view.

In model I have:

```
IQueryable<TabQuotas> quotasIQ = from s in _context.TabQuotas
                                 join s2 in _context.ApplicationUser
                                 on s.Socio equals s2.Socio
                                 select s;
```

And in page/view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TabQuotas) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Socio)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
    <tr>
}
```

"item.socio" which is from the first table in join, works perfect, but "item.Nome" which is from the second table, I can't find out how to retrieve the value from the query. It keep telling me that "TabQuotas" does not contain a definition for "Nome"...
Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by my self.
For those how could have the same question, here is the answer.

First of all we have to create a model with all the values we want to retrieve from the data base.

Then on the .cs file:

```
var quotasIQ = from s in _context.TabQuotas
                             join s2 in _context.ApplicationUser
                             on s.Socio equals s2.Socio
                             select new ListQuotas
                       {
                           Id = q.Id,
                           Email = n.Email
                       };
```

Where ListQuotas is model class we created before.
And that's it.

I hope I can be useful to someone.